# ruby : How to iterate a yml and add elements to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a hash in .yml which I want to iterate and then add its elements to an array of `startup_ports`.

E.g. .yml:

```
instances:
  instance1:
    startup_port: 8811
    shutdown_port: 8822
  instance2:
    startup_port: 9911
    shutdown_port: 9922
```

In my Ruby code:

```
details['instances'].each do |instancename, attribs|
startup_port = attribs[:startup_port]
```

I want to create an array here which stores the `startup_port` for both instances.

Comment: How have you gotten your yaml into your script? Did you use YAML.load_file?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your file is called `example.yml`

```
# assuming your file is in rails root
contents = YAML.load_file('example.yml')
contents['instances'].collect{|key, value| value['startup_port']}
=> [8811, 9911]
```

**UPDATE:**

to append a string

```
contents['instances'].collect{|key, value| "VERSION_#{value['startup_port']}"}
```

Comment: `require 'yaml'` needed?

Comment: great, it gave me the array [8811,9911]. But I want to append a string to each of these too- eg I want  [ VERSION_8811, VERSION_9911 ]. How can I do that?